# Django cannot update another model from a DetailView

Tags: django

I have been stuck trying to build a validation form in a DetailView which compares an argument with flag key and if it is correct it will update some fields in another model (the score field).
This view exists in a Django app ("Challenges") and it presents a model from the given app. However I would like to change two fields from another model.
The other model exists in another app("Accounts". 
However I cannot select the fields I want from the second model. I get an ObjectDoesNotExist exception for

```
u= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk
```

no matter I know that it is there.

The troubling class:

```
class ChallengeDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):
    model = Challenge
    form_class = FlagForm
    def get_success_url(self):
                return reverse('challenges:challenge_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f=form.cleaned_data['flag']
        if f==self.object.flag:
            try:
                u= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
                ch=Challenge.objects.get(flag=f)
                request.user.score+=ch.point
            except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
                 pass
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Maybe the models might also help as well as the FlagForm:

```
class FlagForm(forms.Form):
    flag = forms.CharField()
```

User Model:

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Challenge Model:

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("challenges:challenge_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have also tried to interact with the User model through `self.request.user.score` but it says that there is no such field. 
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: This question isn't clear. *What* is giving you the DoesNotExist option? And why are you always setting User.score to 0?

Comment: `u= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)` this is the culprit

Comment: I apologize. The cause of DoesNotExist is u= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)

Comment: I only meant to set the default value for score to zero.

Comment: it should be `ch.points` not `ch.point`.

Comment: indeed, but it never gets there because of the User model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the below check list. I hope it may help you.

## settings.py

```
# ....
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
# ....
```

## models.py

```
class User(auth.models.AbstractUser):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

## views.py

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    f=form.cleaned_data['flag']
    if f == self.object.flag:
       ch = Challenge.objects.get(flag=f)
       self.request.user.score += ch.point
       self.request.user.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the following which persists no matter if I flush my database.
ERRORS:
accounts.User.is_superuser: (models.E006) The field 'is_superuser' clashes with the field 'is_super
user' from model 'accounts.user'.

Comment: @NikosT I've updated the answer. Please check it now.

Comment: now it changed to django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field 'user_ptr' in class 'User' for parent_link
to base class 'User' clashes with declared field of the same name.

Comment: @NikosT drop the database and create it again and run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Please check out how to implement the custom user in django (https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/)

Comment: I did, but I also had to drop the migrations from each app. And change "request.user.score" to "self.request.user.score". Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @NikosT please accept the answer and give an up-vote. Thanks!

Comment: I did, but I cannot up-vote because my reputation is below the margin of 15. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception is a catchall for all models, I usually prefer to be more specific and use `<Model Name>.DoesNotExist`. Why does it matter? With the snippet, it's not obvious if it's a missing `User` or `Challenge` which raises the exception.

It looks like your view expects a logged in user, but from the code you posted, it doesn't look enforced. Maybe you are accessing the view logged, as anonymous user? You could add the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to your view to ensure it's not the case. If you do that, `request.user` will NOT be an instance of your user, it will be an instance of [Django's `AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser).

You shouldn't need to fetch the user like this: `u= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)`, you can get it more directly like this `u = self.request.user`, and then when you update the profile `request.user.score+=ch.point`, don't forget to save it by calling `user.save()`.

Putting it all together, I think you should be able to rewrite the lines in the try block as follows:

```
u = self.request.user
ch = Challenge.objects.get(flag=f)
u.score += ch.point
u.save()
```

If the problem persists, remove the try/catch to let the original exception propagates, and add the trackback to your post, it's a bit hard to help you more without it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is the User model which causes the trouble.  I planned to add the "LoginRequiredMixin" later.I am logged in, but it does not work this way.